# Pass UserID from user session as @Column in hibernate Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, entity

I have a User hibernate @Entity which has a column CreatedBy. I have this user info (created by) stored in User Session.

```
@Entity
public User

    @Column(name="CreatedBy")
    public createdBy;

}
```

I want that @CreatedBy column should automatically read from user Session. I dont want to set it using setter method.

I am using Spring framework with Hibernate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@PrePersist](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PrePersist.html) and [@PreUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/PreUpdate.html) annotations, specifically the @PrePersist, like this

```
@PrePersist
public void audit () {
     this.createdBy = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
}
```

You can read more from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)

Sorry for my bad english, cheers